# MySQL - how to select id where min/max dates difference is more than 3 years

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
| id |           date     |        user_id         |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1  |     2008-01-01     |          10            |
| 2  |     2009-03-20     |          15            |
| 3  |     2008-06-11     |          10            |
| 4  |     2009-01-21     |          15            |
| 5  |     2010-01-01     |          10            |
| 6  |     2011-06-01     |          10            |
| 7  |     2012-01-01     |          10            |
| 8  |     2008-05-01     |          15            |
```

I’m looking for a solution how to select user_id where the difference between MIN and MAX dates is more than 3 yrs. For the above data I should get:

```
|      user_id        |
-----------------------
|         10          |
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: +1 for a well phrased question from a new user :) Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT   user_id 
FROM     mytable 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING   MAX(`date`) > (MIN(`date`) + INTERVAL '3' YEAR);
```

Tested here: http://sqlize.com/MC0618Yg58

Comment: Interesting approach; I probably would have used `ABS(DATEDIFF(MIN(),MAX())>=365` though--but both are valid. -- Although, if you list `MAX` first, aren't you always guaranteed a positive value, and no need for an `ABS` call?

Comment: Though wouldn't this only get the difference of the years and not of the months and days that seperate it.  Example if it the two dates were 2008-11-01 and 2011-01-01 the year portion are 3 years apart by what you said, but if you look at the month and days it is less than 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to bernie's approach, I'd keep date formats native. I'd also probably list the MAX first as to avoid an `ABS` call (secure a positive number is always returned).

```
SELECT   user_id
FROM     my_table
WHERE    DATEDIFF(MAX(date),MIN(date)) > 365
```

[`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) just returns delta (in days) between two given date fields.

Comment: +1. "Variety's the very spice of life, That gives it all its flavour." --[William Cowper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Cowper) I believe the scalar you want is `1095`, and I'm still not sure what to do about leap-years.

Comment: I think there is a small typo ie `where` instead of `having`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT user_id
 FROM (SELECT user_id, MIN(date) m0, MAX(date) m1
       FROM table
       GROUP by user_id)
HAVING EXTRACT(YEAR FROM m1) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM m0) > 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A.USER_ID FROM TABLE AS A
JOIN TABLE AS B 
ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(A.DATE,B.DATE) > 365
```

Comment: Since when does mysql's [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) have a first argument allowing a metric?

Comment: My apologies.  Corrected.  Got the syntax confused.

Comment: Still realize that `DATEDIFF` returns _days_ not _years_ apart, so you may also want to update to check against 365. ;-)